# Flask 404 Error - Using Flask app Inside a class and called from a different python file - Where am I going wrong?

Tags: python, flask, error-handling, http-status-code-404

## I have a simple flask app inside a class structure so that the flask server can be initiated by calling the call_flaskapp function :

```
|--folder structure
|---------flask_file.py 
|---------main.py
```

#### File name is flask_file

```
from flask import Flask 
class flask_app: 
    def call_flaskapp(self):

        app = Flask(__name__) 

        @app.route('/') 
        def hello_world(): 
            return 'Hello World'

        app.run(debug =True)
```

#### Here the main python file from where I am calling the function:

```
from flask_file import flask_app 

fa = flask_app()
fa.call_flaskapp()
```

#### The server is up and running but whenever I am opening the URL I am getting a 404 error.

I might be doing a silly mistake . Please let me know 
Thanks

Comment: I don't know the details but as far as I know what you are attempting to do is not possible. You don't put the Flask app inside a method or class. I think people can help you better if you tell us what your goal is/why you are doing that. Then people can recommend you different/better approaches to that problem.

Comment: I just changed the port number. It started working LoL XD . Still not sure what was the problem.  @TinNguyen may be my method is wrong but it seems to be working.